Nontrivial metric on $\mathbb{Q}$ making it into a complete metric space
Does there exist a (non-trivial, i.e. not discrete) metric on the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ making it into a complete metric space? What about $\mathbb{N}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$?
For calrification I'm not requiring the metric to be equivalent to the standard metric.

The proposed "similar" question adds the condition that the topology should be the usual topology of $\mathbb Q$.  With that extra condition, the answer is "no".

As $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{N}$, and $\mathbb{Z}$ are all in bijection with each other, making any one of them into a complete metric space will automatically also make the other two into complete metric spaces (via transport of structure).

@GEdgar Very fair, I missed that OP did not want a equivalent metric. Then how about just defining a set $A={0}\cup{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N}$, putting the induced metric from $\mathbb R$ on $A$, and then pushing it to $\mathbb Q$ via a bijection?

@HackR You're right, I don't see why that wouldn't work. But is transporting metric structure possible by any bijection? I would've thought continuity would at least be required. This would need checking since the discrete topology isn't allowed, since the discrete metric isn't allowed, right?

@JohnDoe If you want the transported metric structure to agree with a topology that you already have on the set, then you are going to need some kind of condition about continuity. If you just want a metric on the set and don't care that the topology you end up with is weird, then any bijection works. You're not going to end up with a discrete metric unless the metric you're transporting was already discrete, because the bijection you used will also be an isomorphism between the metric spaces.
